# Why would there be a launch window for a Geosynchronous orbit?

Tags: launch, launch-window

The question is pretty much stated in the title.

Is there anything other than "human caused" reasons for this (such as clearing airspaces, etc.)?

I'm only looking for possible natural reasons (other than weather, assume good weather and clear range). General possibilities that may apply to any aircraft are welcome, even though the SpaceX launch of Intelsat 35e prompted this question.

Comment: Sometimes there are systems reasons (propellant boiloff after umblicals are released, drift of the inertial platform once it is no longer held down, battery charge, validity time-out of the trajectory design based on current wind, etc).  But I have no specific knowledge of that vehicle.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I edited the question to be more general in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics for this launch considerations for airline trafic and shipping could play a part. There might be reasons not to close the range to everyone else indefinetly.

Comment: I thought about that. I would expect a 60 minute window if the reason were "manufactured" as opposed to meteorological or other nature thing. Maybe the range is free for 60 minutes and they give themselves a 1 minute buffer? Seems odd though...

Comment: I've updated my question to exclude things like this.